# Quiero saber como podría mostrar un div oculto cuando clickeo en otro (Solo usando HTML o CSS)

Tags: html, css

Mi idea es simple, aunque no sé si posible (Empecé hace menos de una semana con HTML Y CSS, y todavía estoy explotando lo más posible CSS antes de entrar en JavaScript)
Lo que quiero hacer es que por ejemplo, tengo una imagen, y si yo le hago clic a la imagen, que aparezca un texto que tiene al lado (que esta oculto con el comando opacity: 0;)
Lo que pasa es que se me ocurre hacer
`.img:hover { opacity: 1; }`
Pero no sé cómo hacer para que se comando de Opacity que esta siendo activado por el hover afecte al texto que tiene al lado, y no a la imagen en sí.
Disculpen si no me di a entender, la verdad entiendo lo básico.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.b-logo {
  opacity: 0;
}
    
.div-foto:hover > .b-logo {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div-foto">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lOGOnPr.png" class="logo"><b class="b-logo">Logo Aqui</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Podran ver que pude hacer lo que quería, pero extrañamente si cambias la parte .div-foto:hover > .b-logo { por .logo:hover > .b-logo { ,entonces no funciona y cuando pongo el cursor sobre la imagen no sucede nada.

Comment: Disculpen, no dije que quiero que aparezca cuando haga clic, sino simplemente cuando ponga el cursor sobre la imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `display` para mostrar u ocultar objetos, en [este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) puedes ver las opciones

Si usas `display: none` entonces el elemento no se mostrará y usando algún otro modo entonces se mostrará

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hide {
  display: none;
}
    
.myDIV:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Muestra el elemento al hacer "hover"</h2>

<div class="myDIV">Pon el puntero aquí.</div>
<div class="hide">Ahora soy visible.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la respuesta.
Extrañamente encontré una solución aunque no entiendo cómo. Yo tenía el Div, y dentro la imagen y el texto, y yo ponia el hover en la imagen para que muestre el texto pero no funcionaba. Ahora cambié y puse que el hover sea sobre el div (no sobre la imagen) y da la casualidad que si funciona. Cuando pongo el puntero sobre mi imagen hace aparecer el texto.

Answer (score 1):

Abundando en lo que te respondió @HeytalePazguato, que correctamente mostró el uso de `+` para dar estilo a un elemento sujeto a que se presente en combinación con un determinado sibling. El nombre oficial de este operador es [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Como en la pregunta pusiste que el comportamiento debiera responder a un click, y la respuesta ocupa `hover`, dejo acá mi receta para que la visibilidad de un elemento pueda activarse o desactivarse con un click.

```css
.toggable {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggle:checked+.toggable {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="toggle_label" for="toggle">Click para mostrar/ocultar</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="toggable">Me ven?</div>
</div>
```

Básicamente, utilizo un checkbox (porque tiene estado, y el seudoselector `:checked` me permite condicionar a sus elementos adyacentes). Tenemos un elemento `.toggable` invisible en condiciones normales y declaramos un estilo:

```
#toggle:checked + .toggable {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Dice que, cuando es precedido por un checkbox checkeado, tiene opacidad 1.

Esta misma técnica se ocupa para darle estilo a los checkboxes en librerías UI. En realidad le dan estilo al label reactivo al estado checked. En el siguiente ejemplo ocultamos el input y usamos el label para indicar el estado.

```css
#toggle+label::before {
  content: 'Click para mostrar'
}

#toggle:checked+label::before {
  content: 'Click para ocultar'
}

.toggable {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .toggable {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

label {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background-color: #0063bf;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked+label {
  color: #0063bf;
  background-color: #99ccff;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
  <div class="toggable">Me ven?</div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo fíjate que el label está entre el input y el contenedor invisible, por lo que usé el estilo

```
#toggle:checked ~ .toggable {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Que condiciona el estilo sin requerir que los elementos sean consecutivos.

Answer (score 0):

espero estés bien!
voy agregar las 2 opcione, una onclick con solo css y la otra :hover espero te sirvan!

#### index.html

```html
<!-- onclick -->
<div id="onclick">
  <input id="mostrar" type="checkbox" name="mostrar"/>
  <label for="mostrar">mostrar</label>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642019275442-d9622e4a27ab?crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NDY3MTYwMw&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;q=80&amp;w=400" alt=""/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
</div>

<!-- hover -->

<div id="hover">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642019275442-d9622e4a27ab?crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NDY3MTYwMw&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;q=80&amp;w=400" alt=""/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
</div>
```

¡Es hora del **CSS**!

Lo primero que debemos hacer es darle un tamaño al `<div id="onclick">` y al `<div id="hover"` (digamos 200px) y también un `position relative` (esto es importante) para que el contenido no se desborde al usar un `position:absolute;` en lo elementos anidados. Tambien agrego un float irrelevante y un margin, solo para que se vea lindo jajaja

```
#onclick, #hover { width: 200px; position: relative; float: left; margin: 0 1em; }
```

El **input #onclick** lo seteamos con  `#onclick input{display: none;}`
Nuestro  va a ser la jugada secreta, le agrego a este un `cursor: pointer;` esto servirá para que al momento de pasar el mouse sobre la imagen de a entender que tiene una acción.

```
#onclick label {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Al tag **#onclick img, #hover img** le agregamos un **width** del **100%** del **div** contenedor: `#onclick img, #hover img { width: 100%; }`

agregamos la opacidad al texto: `#onclick p, #hover p {opacity: 0;`

por último agregamos el evento *onclick* para mostrar el texto:

```
#mostrar:checked ~ p { opacity: 1; }
```

Para que el evento *hover* se lance le agregamos a el **div** contenedor

```
#hover:hover p { opacity: 1; }
```

la virgulilla `~` funciona como un buscador del tag, clase, id, type; cuando lo encuentra lanza el evento.

#### style.css

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#onclick,
#hover {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#onclick input {
  display: none;
}

#onclick label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#onclick img,
#hover img {
  width: 100%;
}

#onclick p,
#hover p {
  opacity: 0;
}

#onclick #mostrar:checked ~ p {
  opacity: 1;
}

#hover:hover p{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Saludos!